# If $f:S^n\to \Bbb R^{n+1}$ is a continuous function satisfying $f(x)=t(x) x$ for all $x\in S^n$ then $t:S^n\to \Bbb R$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

Suppose $f:S^n\to \Bbb R^{n+1}$  is a continuous function satisfying $f(x)=t(x) x$ for all $x\in S^n$, where $t(x)\in \Bbb R$. Regarding $t$ as a function $S^n\to \Bbb R$, is $t$ necessarily continuous?

I've seen this statement in the proof of showing that the canonical line bundle over $\Bbb RP^n$ is not trivial, but I can't see why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because since $x \in \Bbb S^n$, then $\langle x,x\rangle = 1$, so applying $\langle \cdot, x\rangle$ on both sides of $f(x) = t(x)x$, one gets that $t(x) = \langle f(x),x\rangle$. It follows that $t$ has the same regularity as $f$ since the $\langle \cdot,x\rangle$ operation is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks. I've need to wait 10minutes to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence in $S^n$ converging to $x\in S^n.$ Then $f(x_j)\to f(x)$ because $f$ is continuous. So $|t(x_j)|=\|f(x_j)\|\to \|f(x)\|=\|t(x)x\|=|t(x)|.$

So $s=(t(x_j))_j$ is a bounded sequence.

Now $s$  has no sub-sequence $u=(t(x_j))_{j\in A}$ (for some infinite $A\subset \Bbb N$) converging to any $r\ne t(x).$

Because if $u\to r$ and $x_j\to x$ then $(f(x_j))_{j\in A}=(t(x_j)x_j)_{j\in A}\to rx.$ But $rx \ne t(x)x$ if $\|x\|=1$ and $r\ne t(x).$

So any convergent sub-sequence of the bounded sequence $s$ converges to $t(x).$ So $s$ converges to $t(x).$